# Relationship between the <header> and <h1> tags in HTML5

Tags: html, html-heading

The  element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I would explain this by an example.
A lion living in a jungle marks its territory and no other male is allowed to rule there. In the same way,  tag is a territory where the header information is put and  tag is used to highlight the lion i.e the important statement, title , etc.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's confusing. The head element contains meta data about the document. The header element contains any items that should contain introductory information and often includes things like h1 elements, logos, and things about the author or company. Very often, it will also contain a navigation bar. The h1 tag stands for heading and helps to structure your document and tell web browsers/screen readers and others the importance of that element.